# How to use gradle BoM with annotation processor?

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, annotation-processing, kapt

I’m trying to define all my dependencies in a bill of materials (BoM) platform module so the other modules in my multi-module project can use the same versions. All works fine except the kapt dependencies. In those I get this error:

```
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:kaptDebugKotlin'.
> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:kapt'.
   > Could not find com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:.
     Required by:
         project :app
```

For example with this platform (`:bom`) module:

```
plugins {
  id 'java-platform'
}
dependencies {
  constraints {
    api 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.25.2'
    api 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.25.2'
  }
}
```

I'm getting that error when I use it like this in the app module:

```
dependencies {
  implementation platform(project(':bom'))
  implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger'
  kapt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler'
  // ...
}
```

I’m getting the same error if I use `annotationProcessor`. If I set the version like `kapt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.25.2'` all works.

What am I doing wrong? Can I use BoM for `kapt` or `annotationProcessor`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you are missing `kapt platform(project(':bom'))`

kapt doesn't include dependencies from implementation, so it doesn't include the platform either